# Using the table head <th> colspan attribute using styled-components

Tags: html, css, styled-components

The `colspan` attribute works fine on a table built with HTML & CSS.

```css
th, td { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Major 1</th>
      <th colspan="2">Major 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
      <th>col3</th>
      <th>col4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to implement this very same thing using `styled-components`.

```js
const styled = window.styled;

const LS = {};

LS.TableHead_TH = styled.th`
  /* THINGS I'VE TRIED IN HERE */
  colspan: 2;
  col-span: 2;
  column-span: 2;  /* <--- THIS IS SUGGESTED BY AUTOCOMPLETE */
`;

function Table() {
  return(
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <LS.TableHead_TH>Major 1</LS.TableHead_TH>
          <LS.TableHead_TH>Major 2</LS.TableHead_TH>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data1</td>
          <td>data2</td>
          <td>data3</td>
          <td>data4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
th, td { border: 1px solid black }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

But as you can see from the snippet, it does not work. And I've tried several properties.

---

If I send it as a regular attribute on my JSX, it still works. Like:

```
  <LS.TableHead_TH colspan="2">Major 1</LS.TableHead_TH>
  <LS.TableHead_TH colspan="2">Major 2</LS.TableHead_TH>
```

**UPDATE:** Actually the code above worked here on SO. But on my local environment, I had to pass it camelCased, like `colSpan`

```
  <LS.TableHead_TH colSpan="2">Major 1</LS.TableHead_TH>
  <LS.TableHead_TH colSpan="2">Major 2</LS.TableHead_TH>
```

What am i doing wrong?

PS: Tested only in Chrome, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this, because `colspan` is an HTML attribute, and not a CSS property. Sometimes I'm confused by these two concepts.

The `column-span` suggested by the auto-complete is realted to multiple columns layout, and not to be used on `<table>`.

The `camelCased` probably was demanded by `React` JSX, even though the original attribute is not separated by hyphen.

Comment: You can add attributes via js if you do not want them added in your html template.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use CSS grid to lay the table out, with `grid-column: span 2`; in your styled component. Like this:

```js
const styled = window.styled;

const LS = {};

LS.TableHead_TH = styled.th`
  grid-column: span 2;
`;

function Table() {
  return(
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <LS.TableHead_TH>Major 1</LS.TableHead_TH>
          <LS.TableHead_TH>Major 2</LS.TableHead_TH>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>data1</td>
          <td>data2</td>
          <td>data3</td>
          <td>data4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
th, td { border: 1px solid black }
table { 
  display:grid;
  width:-moz-fit-content;
  width:fit-content;
  gap:2px;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4, auto);
}
thead,tbody,tfoot, tr {
  display:contents;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/styled-components@4.0.1/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

---

<sub>Probably requires Chromium-based Edge to work in MS browsers.</sub>